# Adding App Events in iOS app produces undeclared identifier 'AppEvent'

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to add facebook app events, and I installed FacebookSDK. Then I have next code:

```
import FacebookCore

static func logViewContentEvent(contentType : String, contentData : String, contentId : String, currency : String, price : Double) {
        let params : AppEvent.ParametersDictionary = [
            .contentType : contentType,
            .content : contentData,
            .contentId : contentId,
            .currency : currency
        ]
        let event = AppEvent(name: .viewedContent, parameters: params, valueToSum: price)
        AppEventsLogger.log(event)
    }
```

But I get error from the title. What I am doing wrong, and why this type is missing?

Comment: what is `.viewedContent`in the name param of AppEvent?

Comment: @AndresGomez I wonder that too. That is code generated by facebook's app event code generator for the ViewContent event.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios#predefined-events

Comment: have you tried to change `. viewedContent` for some string?

Comment: Its not only that. @AndresGomez the problem is AppEvent is undeclared, so it doesn't compile. I don't know what I should import so to make that type available.

Comment: try `import FBSDKCoreKit`

Comment: I have that it imported, and FacebookCore as well.

Comment: I have the same issue. The docs are really bad! I'm not even sure which pods to include. `FacebookCore` doesn't seem to be necessary to log events which I do with `AppEvents.log(AppEvents.Name("foobar"))` . But I cannot log custom events!

Comment: how did you add the sdk? pod? carthage?

Comment: I added it using pod. @Teffi

Comment: @Whirlwind got that. Shared you my setup and it works for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a [knowed](https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-swift-sdk/issues/454) facebook annoying issue.

Before [FBSDK 5.0.1](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/5.x-branch) your code works well. After, you can change your code with for example:

```
static func logViewContentEvent(contentType : String, contentData : String, contentId : String, currency : String, price : Double) {
        let params =  [
            "contentType": contentType,
            "content" : contentData,
            "contentID" : contentId,
            "currency" : currency
        ]
        AppEvents.logEvent(AppEvents.Name(rawValue: "viewedContent"), valueToSum: price, parameters: params)
    }
```

Comment: It works like this, but its kinda hacky way to achive what I wanted. Well, its only solution for now I guess. Thanks for the answer man.

Answer (score 4):

In top of file get rid of FacebookCore use only

```
         import FBSDKCoreKit
         // implemented  FBSDKCoreKit (5.8.0)
         let event =  "custom event"
         AppEvents.logEvent(AppEvents.Name.init(rawValue: event))
```

or with parameters

```
    let a:[String: String] = ["key": "value"]
    AppEvents.logEvent(AppEvents.Name.init(rawValue: event), parameters: a )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have mine working with these set up:

- Installed via cocoapod with `use_frameworks!` configuration

`pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 5.11.1'`

- Since my project supports both ObjC and Swift I imported `<FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>` on the bridging file

```
static func logContent(id: String, type: String, valueToSum: Double) {
        AppEvents.logEvent(.viewedContent,
                           valueToSum: valueToSum,
                           parameters: [contentType: type,
                                        contentID: id,
                                        currency: "USD"])
    }
```

Comment: This ways work for me to. Checkout actually my code in original question. There is no type AppEvent etc... AppEvents exists.

Comment: oh. sorry. I missed out that you're referring to logging custom events. Let me try and see if I can find something that will help

Comment: I am trying to log standard events with the code generated with Facebook code generator. The code is broken, it doesnt work. What you are posting works for me to.

Comment: @Whirlwind Sorry for the confusion. I would stick with what Alessandro Ornano suggested. I think the docs are probably outdated and `AppEvent` is something they've entirely removed.